# Curling Express server is failing with multiple arguments

Tags: node.js, curl, express

I am trying to curl my local server to create a message but am getting strange errors. I am able to create a user using curl just fine:

```
$curl --data userToken='awdawd' localhost:3000/usertoken
>>>created
```

But when I try to post to /messages route I get the following:

```
$curl -data x="10"&y="10"&z="10"&message="hello"&userToken="mrTony" http://localhost:3000/messages

>>>[1] 26248
>>>[2] 26249
>>>[3] 26250
>>>[4] 26251
>>>-bash: http://localhost:3000/messages: No such file or directory
>>>[2]   Done                    y="10"
>>>[3]-  Done                    z="10"
>>>[4]+  Done                    message="hello"
>>>curl: (6) Could not resolve host: x=10

>>> [1]+  Exit 6                  curl -data x="10"
```

I thought that maybe there was a content type issue, so I tried including the content type as application/json,  but I still get the same error.

Here is my express server routes:

```
  //input: {userToken: string}
  router.post('/usertoken', function (req, res) {
    var token = req.body.userToken;
    models.createUser(token).then(
      util.resolvePOST.bind(this, req, res),
      util.rejectPOST.bind(this, req, res)
      );
  });

  //input: {x: float, y: float, z: float, message: string, userToken: string}
  router.post('/messages', function(req, res) {
    console.log('does not work', req.body);
    models.createMessage(req.body).then(
      util.resolvePOST.bind(this, req, res),
      util.rejectPOST.bind(this, req, res)
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not your express app that is the issue, but the way you are calling curl. Your shell is seeing the `&` and putting things into the background. So you need to make sure that they all are contained within quotes so that the shell doesn't process them.

Try this instead:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/messages?x=10&y=10&z=10&message=hello&userToken=mrTony"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "&" in your line are confusing linux. Basically, when you use that in your command line, it's telling it to run the command as a background process.

You need to enclose everything in quotes, have you tried?:

```
$curl -data 'x="10"&y="10"&z="10"&message="hello"&userToken="mrTony"' http://localhost:3000/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to followup on the two correct answers here, you should be able to backslash escape the ampersands instead.

```
$curl -data x="10"\&y="10"\&z="10"\&message="hello"\&userToken="mrTony" http://localhost:3000/messages
```